# MQTTClient_setCallbacks() will always create socket and not close it

Tags: c, linux, file, mqtt

My System OS is Linux, Use C for development, My MQTT Library is "paho-MQTT"

The simple application below will run for a while before generating a "open too much files" error. I have attempted to diagnose using `losf` command to find out what is the fd not closed.

I believed I had traced the issue to the MQTT Function "MQTTClient_setCallbacks()" but that seems OK. Currently I'm unable to find out the true cause of the error.

Note: When this problem occurs, the device has no external network capability, so will be in an infinite loop attempting to connect.

My code is below as:

```
int InternalSock::MQTTSubscribe()
{
    MQTTClient client;
    MQTTClient_connectOptions conn_opts = MQTTClient_connectOptions_initializer;
    int rc;
    int ch;
    const char *TOPIC=ModTcpIPA->DC1SN[0];
    const char *address;
    if (ModTcpIPA->ThirdPartyMode == 1) {
        address = "ws://52.163.118.233:8080";   //3rd party 
    }
    else {
        address = "ws://52.187.179.41:8080";    //delta
    }

    const char *client_id=ModTcpIPA->DC1SN[0];
    char *chs = ModTcpIPA->DC1SN[0];
    char **topic=&chs;
    disconnectflag = 1;
    ModTcpIPA->MQTTSubscribing = 0;
    MQTTClient_create(&client, address, client_id, MQTTCLIENT_PERSISTENCE_NONE, NULL);
    conn_opts.keepAliveInterval = 30;
    conn_opts.cleansession = 0;
    if (ModTcpIPA->ThirdPartyMode == 1) {
        conn_opts.username = THIRDPARTYUSERNAME;
        conn_opts.password = THIRDPARTYPASSWORD;
    }
    else {
        conn_opts.username = DELTAUSERNAME;
        conn_opts.password = DELTAPASSWORD;
    }
    conn_opts.MQTTVersion = MQTTVERSION_3_1;

    while(!ModTcpIPA->CloseMQTTThread){
        if(disconnectflag == 1){
            MQTTClient_setCallbacks(client, NULL, connlost, msgarrvd, delivered);  
            disconnectflag = 0;
        }
        if ((rc = MQTTClient_connect(client, &conn_opts)) != MQTTCLIENT_SUCCESS)
        {
            //if(ModTcpIPA->CloudRegist_st == 1){
                printf("Failed to connect, return code %d\n", rc);
            //}
        }else{
            printf("Subscribing to topic %s\nfor client %s using QoS%d\n\n"
               "Press Q<Enter> to quit\n\n", TOPIC, client_id, QOS);
            MQTTClient_subscribe(client, TOPIC, QOS);
            ModTcpIPA->MQTTSubscribing = 1;
            while(disconnectflag == 0){
                if(strlen(MQTTBuff)!= 0){
                    ParseMQTTMsg(&client);
                }
                sleep(1);
            }
            ModTcpIPA->MQTTSubscribing = 0;
            MQTTClient_unsubscribe(client, TOPIC);
            MQTTClient_disconnect(client, 10000);
        }
        sleep(3);
    }
    MQTTClient_destroy(&client);
    return rc;
}
```

add callback functions:

```c
void delivered(void *context, MQTTClient_deliveryToken dt)
{
    printf("Message with token value %d delivery confirmed\n", dt);
    deliveredtoken = dt;
}

int msgarrvd(void *context, char *topicName, int topicLen, MQTTClient_message *message)
{
    int i;
    char* payloadptr;

    printf("Message arrived\n");
    printf("     topic: %s\n", topicName);
    printf("   message: ");

    payloadptr = (char*)message->payload;
    for(i=0; i<message->payloadlen; i++)
    {
        putchar(*payloadptr++);
    }
    putchar('\n');
    memset(MQTTBuff, '\0', sizeof(MQTTBuff));
    memcpy(MQTTBuff, message->payload, message->payloadlen);
    MQTTClient_freeMessage(&message);
    MQTTClient_free(topicName);
    return 1;
}

void connlost(void *context, char *cause)
{
    printf("\nConnection lost\n");
    printf("     cause: %s\n", cause);
    disconnectflag = 1;
}
```

Comment: [Eclipse Paho](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/) is open source and the page for the [c client](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/index.php?page=clients/c/index.php) contains a link to the [Git repository](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.c) containing the source. The function you are looking for is [here](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.c/blob/master/src/MQTTClient.c#L1038) but I suspect the issue is probably in the callback functions you are providing.

Comment: Hi Brits, thank you for your reply, I get the source code!  Regarding the "callback functions" you mentioned, I just checked again and didn't see anything suspicious. I posted my code. Could you please help me view it once?

Comment: (warning - don't program in C any more so advice may be worthless!) Based on your code I'm not sure you need the asynchronous functionality? Using the [synchronous client](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/files/mqttdoc/MQTTClient/html/async.html) ([example](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.c/blob/master/src/samples/paho_cs_sub.c)) may simplify things (your handling of `MQTTBuff` does not look very thread safe to me). Also check you have the latest version of the library, add the exact error message to your question and perhaps check the payload is not bigger that `MQTTBuff`.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that when this problem occurs, the device has no external network capability, so MQTTBuffer has not been used yet, so I don't think the problem lies here, or do you have other opinions?
How to confirm whether the MQTT version is the latest version?

In addition, about the synchronous method. Thank you very much for providing it to me. I will try it later.

Comment: [latest is here](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/iot.paho/downloads); see [this re determining version](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58846/viewing-linux-library-executable-version-info). [This issue](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.c/issues/831) may be what you are seeing (but Ian was a little vague re what fixed it!). You could move `MQTTClient_setCallbacks` out of the loop (but cant see anything in that function that would cause the issue you are having).

Comment: Thank you for your kind of help!!
The Issue situation is different with me, I start MQTT process and never connected Server.
I have a important unfolding, I find the key point is when my linux system network set static type for eth0 and the Gateway IP setting is wrong, the issue will happen, I see the socket keep increase with "lsof", If I mark MQTTClient_setCallbacks() function or setting correct gateway IP, the issue will not happen. So I guest MQTTClient_setCallbacks have some error on the situation.
What do you think?  Is there any solution for the next step beside update version?

Comment: Calling `MQTTClient_setCallbacks()` sets the client into async mode which will change it's behaviour in a number of ways. For example [when connecting](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.c/blob/master/src/MQTTClient.c#L1180) it starts `MQTTClient_run`. So it's quite understandable that removing this line would alter the behaviour and, perhaps, avoid a bug. It is not clear what the cause of issue [#1833](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.c/issues/831) was but as it refers to a "socket leak when reconnecting" it may be the cause of your problem; updating is a good first step.